# Unable to open file.txt with c++

Tags: c++, file, text, vector, fstream

I've looked up similar posts here, but none seem to be doing the job for my question. **I'm basically trying take a sequence of words in a .txt file and put each word in a vector, and printing each value afterwards.** For example, we have *I love racing cars* in *array.txt*, and I want my vector to have "I" at position 0, "love" at 1 and so on. Unfortunately, **the code does not access "array.txt", so it never executes the code in the if condition.** 
Now I've heard that by using the fstream library it should work just fine, but the file is never found. I suspect that it doesn't work because it cannot find the path, but I have never opened files in C++. Also, I have not put my file anywhere in my project folder.

Some changes I've already tried:

- file.open("array.txt");
- omitting file.close();
- include "C:\array.txt"; (with the # in front)
- file.open("C:\array.txt")

And I'm using Windows 10, if this matters.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;
#include <vector>;
#include <fstream>;
//#include <"C:\Users\Samer El-Hage\Documents">;
using namespace std;

void main(){
    vector<string> v (10);
    ifstream file;
    file.open("C:\array.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            file >> v[i];
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else cout << "Could not access file.";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

**This code prints "Could not access file."**

Comment: in the `file.open` statement, use `C:\\array.txt` - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: Use either forward slashes: `"C:/array.txt"`, an escaped backslash: `"C:\\array.txt"` or a raw string literal: `R"(C:\array.txt)"`. Also, you have unnecessary semi-colons after your includes. (In fact, in a Treat Warnings as Errors setup, this won't compile!)

Comment: BTW, the `main()` function returns **int**.  Always.  Look it up.

Answer (score 4):

The file cannot be opened because the file system can't find the file named "[Bell]rray.txt". the character sequence '\a' is the "Make my computer Beep" character.

Use either forward slashes: `"C:/array.txt"`, an escaped backslash: `"C:\\array.txt"` or a raw string literal: `R"(C:\array.txt)"`

The file must also exist at the specified location. If you do not provide a drive and just say `"array.txt"` the location defaults to wherever the executable is (or in an IDE, the Working Directory).

Also, you have unnecessary semi-colons after your includes. (In fact, in a Treat Warnings as Errors setup, this won't compile!)

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I had not put the .txt file in my folder with the source code, which, strangely enough, was not mentioned in my previous search results... I got to search better!

Answer (score 1):

`\a` simply turns the computer beep on. Try writing `"C:\\array.txt"` instead in the `open` call.

Answer (score -1):

Try not calling open explicitly:

```
ifstream file ("array.txt");
```

Look at the examples here:[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: The issue is that "\a" in the "C:\array.txt", is the escape sequence for the bell or alarm sound.  Search the internet for "c++ escape sequences".